# Not in,in and "=" operators sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
CARS(CCODE,ADDRESS,CITY,COLOR)
CARS_CONTRACT(CON_CODE,ST_dATE,END_dATE,PNAME,MONTHLYPRICE,CCODE)
```

find ccode and address with city='new-york' for which montlyprice have been greate than 500 evro and for which more than 7 contracts have been signed, so my code is

my code is..

```
select ccode,address
from cars c,cars_contract cd
where c.ccode=cd.ccode and city='new-york'
and ccode not in(select ccode from cars_contract where monthlyprice<500
group by ccode,address
having count(*)>7
```

my question is can i replace the above code with

this

```
select ccode,address
from cars c,cars_contract cd
where c.ccode=cd.ccode and city='new-york'
and monthlyprice>500
group by ccode,address
having count(*)>7
```

or this? (to be specific do i have to specify join condition in internal clause?)

```
select ccode,address
from cars c,cars_contract cd
where c.ccode=cd.ccode and city='new-york'
and ccode in(select ccode from cars_contract where monthlyprice>500)
group by ccode,address
having count(*)>7
```

Comment: Avoid deprecated syntax, use explicit `JOIN` and `ON`.  Beyond that, it depends on if you want the filtering to apply to the subquery or not.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you provide sample input and output? Also, as already asked, please indicate whether this is MySQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra subquery - just use an ANSI join instead of implicit and fully qualify all your columns to make sure ccode use isn't ambiguous, i.e.:

```
SELECT c.ccode, c.address
FROM cars c
    INNER JOIN cars_contract cd ON c.ccode = cd.ccode 
WHERE c.city = 'new-york'
AND cd.monthlyprice > 500
GROUP BY c.ccode, c.address
HAVING COUNT(*) > 7;
```

Comment: That's a good catch, I completely missed DISTINCT won't have any impact with GROUP BY. Thanks for reminding :)